# arm-none-ebai-gcc does not work from mounted directory

Tags: mount, compiling, gcc

I want to build project for ARM micro controller. For this purpose in folder with project was placed script, which download toolchain and build him. After run this script toolchain was placed in folder with project. Folder with project placed on another logical disk (which shared between Win and Linux) and this disk is mounting each time when I start develop. (Mount by hand).
When I start `make`, in terminal I receive error:

```
make[3]: arm-none-eabi-gcc: Command not found
```

The output from `echo $PATH`:

```
/mnt/Smoothie-master/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

The output from `whereis arm-none-ebai-gcc`:

```
arm-none-ebai-gcc:
```

All binaries files, which are relating to this toolchain are placed in the next directory:

```
/mnt/Smoothie-master/gcc-arm-none-eabi/bin/
```

and has permissions: "-rwxrwxrwx"

Before building this toolchain, I had another similar toolchain (another version of this), but installed through `apt-get`. And it was removed through `apt-get` before building new.

Where is the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Problem was the next: my Ubuntu is 64-bit. So for the correct work need to install "libc6-dev-i386".
Now it works!